# Extract an Excel cell value from dynamic array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to extract a single value from a dynamic array in Excel. I only want the number highlighted orange from the "Value" column in my table named "FRAM_abundance_harvest".

[image]

The filter function below gets me the entire row of data, but I only want the value (356,034) to be returned.

```
`=FILTER(FRAM_abundance_harvest,((FRAM_abundance_harvest[Source]="Ocean") *
(FRAM_abundance_harvest[Abundance_Harvest]="Abundance") *
(FRAM_abundance_harvest[Mark status]="Marked") *
(FRAM_abundance_harvest[Run type]="Late") *
(FRAM_abundance_harvest[Production type]="Hatchery")))`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the whole formula within an `INDEX()` Function, as shown in image below,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

```
=INDEX(FILTER(FRAM_abundance_harvest,
((FRAM_abundance_harvest[Source]="Ocean") *
(FRAM_abundance_harvest[Abundance_Harvest]="Abundance") *
(FRAM_abundance_harvest[Mark Status]="Marked") *
(FRAM_abundance_harvest[Run Type]="Late") *
(FRAM_abundance_harvest[Production Type]="Hatchery")),""),,6)
```

Or, Please note that **O365** is required for the below function as well,
**[DROP()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/drop-function-1cb4e151-9e17-4838-abe5-9ba48d8c6a34)** Function is still in the Insider's **BETA**-channels.

[image: USING_DROP]

```
=DROP(FILTER(FRAM_abundance_harvest,
((FRAM_abundance_harvest[Source]="Ocean") *
(FRAM_abundance_harvest[Abundance_Harvest]="Abundance") *
(FRAM_abundance_harvest[Mark Status]="Marked") *
(FRAM_abundance_harvest[Run Type]="Late") *
(FRAM_abundance_harvest[Production Type]="Hatchery")),""),,5)
```

Comment: To simulate the TOP(1) function in SQL: use Index(Array,1,,1) to get the first value.

Answer (score 1):

### `INDEX/MATCH` vs `SUMIFS` in an Excel Table

**The First Occurrence (INDEX/MATCH)**

- This is an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FRAM_abundance_harvest[Value],
MATCH(1,(FRAM_abundance_harvest[Source]="Ocean")
*(FRAM_abundance_harvest[Abundance_Harvest]="Abundance")
*(FRAM_abundance_harvest[Run_Type]="Late")
*(FRAM_abundance_harvest[Production_Type]="Hatchery")
*(FRAM_abundance_harvest[Mark_Status]="Marked"),0)),"")
```

**The Sum (SUMIFS)**

```
=SUMIFS(FRAM_abundance_harvest[Value],
FRAM_abundance_harvest[Source],"Ocean",
FRAM_abundance_harvest[Abundance_Harvest],"Abundance",
FRAM_abundance_harvest[Run_Type],"Late",
FRAM_abundance_harvest[Production_Type],"Hatchery",
FRAM_abundance_harvest[Mark_Status],"Marked")
```

- If no match is found, the first will return "" while the second will return 0.
- IMO, the `SUMIFS` formula seems more relevant.
- You could use five cells for the five columns and replace the hardcoded values with the cell references. Also, you could create dropdowns in the mentioned cells and easily change the result for different values of the five columns.

[image]